# Vapor 3: Route with arbitrary path segments

Tags: swift, vapor

I'm working on a Vapor 3 app that uses the requesting path as the argument for the method that responds. For instance:

http://localhost:8080/monitor/some/test/path

That can be handled by a single endpoint, the `monitor` endpoint in this case, which would then ideally give me access to the rest of the URL, `/some/test/path`.

I've composed a route in Vapor that doesn't work using wildcard variables, and tried the `group` mechanic as described in the docs, to no avail. My expectation from using other web frameworks is that something like "/monitor/*" should do the job but I can't find anything in the documentation to suggest it.

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match any single path parameter, use the `any` path component. If you want to match any number of path parameters, use the `all` path component.

For example, if I register a route with these path components:

```
"service", any, "api", "users"
```

It will match these routes:

- `/service/v1/api/users`
- `/service/caleb/api/users`

But it won't match these:

- `service/v1/beta/api/users`
- `service/v1`

However, if you use the `all` component, like this:

```
"service", "api", all
```

You can match any of the following:

- `/service/api/v1`
- `/service/api/v1/users/caleb`

But not `/service/api`.